# Laravel Passport for First Party Apps

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I want to be able to use Laravel Passport to consume my API. I only want first party apps to use it (My web app and my mobile app).

I don't want the user to be logged in order to access the API on the web nor the mobile app.

I put some routes under the `auth_client` middleware and pass an `access_token` that I got with a `client_credentials` grant.

Other routes I put under `auth:api` and I pass a token that I got through the `password` grant.

Problem with this, is that I can't consume the routes under `auth_client` from my web app.

Pretty much I would want a way to protect my API from third parties, while still being able to use it in my web app and my mobile app.

Comment: If you use something like Dingo, it allows you to use a dispatcher and do internal requests right at your backend